# Selecting Particular records from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql table as follows

```
Desc   code1   code2   type1  type2
-------------------------------------    
desc1  123     234     T       M
desc2  444     421     T       M
desc3  491     212     T 
desc4  322     211     T
desc5  333     312     T
```

Now I have to select first two records every time and one from remaining three records based on some conditions, how select only three records from this table first, second and one from remaining three... please help

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table ORDER BY (something)
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE (something) (maybe ORDER BY something)
```

OR if by top 2 you mean the records where type2=M then:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table WHERE type2='M'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE (something)
```

OR if you want the top 2 and some random third, then

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM table WHERE type2='M'
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table WHERE type2<>'M' ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT TOP (2)* FROM TOPP
  UNION 
  SELECT TOP(1) * FROM TOPP A 
  WHERE A.DESC NOT IN (SELECT TOP((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TOPP)-3) DESC FROM TOPP)
```

TableName = Topp